# Listening to new ActiveMQ topic as they created in runtime

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic

I am working on application (spring boot application)which is supposed to be listening from the topic created in runtime from some other application.

How can I know a new topic is created on the Active MQ Brocker in the runtime?
And how can I start to listening the newly created topic un the runtime?

Please note that I want to listen to topic created in runtime not at launch time (application startup, spring application context is built).

I don't know how many topic I may have to listen to when my application starts up. Topics are created in the runtime with no specific naming pattern.

Comment: [This](http://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-topics-and-queues-in-a-broker.html) might be a good starting point.  But how to determine the format/structure of a message in the new topic?

Comment: Format and structure of messages from all topics is same and is known in advance.

Comment: What is the purpose of different topics if they all have the same format/structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without 'durability' in place, this presents a race condition. If the producer sends a message before the consumer is online, the broker will not hold on to the message for the consumer. 'durability' is the broker holding on to messages for a consumer, even when the consumer is not connected.

However! ActiveMQ has this solved by using wild card names for consumers. It is recommended that you at least agree on a prefix to provide first level filtering. Note-- you'll also want this if you go to multi-broker architecture. Something like topic://ORDER.ABCD, topic://ORDER.XYZ where all the topics are created with the same format ie 'ORDER.$randomStuff'.

Option 1:
Have the consumer register a durable subscription using ActiveMQ's wild card character ">".  ie. topic://ORDER.>

Option 2:
You can listen for events on the ActiveMQ.Advisory topics for when the destination is created, and then register a consumer. However, this has the race condition where messages could be missed.

Option 1 is probably your best bet, but can run into scaling problems if you start getting up to the message load in the 100M's of messages per day or 1000's of total number of topics.

Comment: We did agree on naming pattern for the topic name, so I could use wild card.

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe to the advisory topic `ActiveMQ.Advisory.Topic` (advisories need to be enabled -- see [1]). A message will be published to this topic every time a topic is created. The message will have as its body an object of class `org.apache.activemq.command.DestinationInfo`, from which the name of the new topic can be extracted.

The application can subscribe using this name, as it would to any other topic.

[1] http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html

Comment: Didn’t try the solution but as we agreed to naming pattern of topic , I used wild card.